# Unable to run yum command on Redhat 7

Tags: rhel, yum

I have a new Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3, I am trying to install Ambari Server on this machine by following the steps in the link

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_download_the_ambari_repo_lnx7.html

I am able to run the first step i.e

```
wget -nv http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.1.0/ambari.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo
```

But when I am executing the next steps `yum repolist` or `yum install ambari-server` I am getting the following error.

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager


rhn-plugin: RPM error.  The message was:
Could not determine what version of Red Hat Linux you are running.
If you get this error, try running 

        rpm --rebuilddb
```

I ran the above command but it did not solve my problem. I tried to search for the answer but I did not find anything on the internet.

Can anyone identify this problem?

Comment: `uname -a` and `/etc/issue` please

Comment: Output of `uname -a` Linux <machinename>.corporate.local 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 16 13:15:13 EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Ravi, You used RHEL 7.3 but the repo just supported RHEL 7.2.The repo didnt support  RHEL 7.3 yet.You got this error "Could not determine what version of Red Hat Linux you are running."

Comment: @Ravi, You used RHEL 7.3 but the repo just supported RHEL 7.2.The repo didnt support  RHEL 7.3 yet.You got this error "Could not determine what version of Red Hat Linux you are running."

Comment: is there any way out of this problem except waiting for yum to support 7.3?